# Двоичный код, как разделить по 4 символа

Tags: c++

Я не понимаю как грамотно сделать, что бы при выводе ответа - символы делились по 4 части (не так(10101010) -> а вот так (1010 1010))

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Insert a number from 0 to 255: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Answer: ";

    for (int i = 128; i > 0; i /= 2) 
    {
        if (x >= i) 
        {
            cout << "1";
            x = x - i;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "0";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Блин.. Даже битовых операций нет...

Comment: >  символы делились на 4 части - эти "части" называются _тетрадами_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Insert a number from 0 to 255: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Answer: ";

    for (int i = 128; i > 0; i /= 2) 
    {
        if (i == 8)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        if (x >= i) 
        {
            cout << "1";
            x = x - i;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "0";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: только для оответа не нужно весь код представлять. Достаточно сказать, что нужно добавить в цикл